# cant get any matches from before 1.1.2021

Tags: riot-games-api

I am trying to get that data for my last 500 games. However the maximum amount of games I seem to be able to get is 266. The last game in that list I played on January 1st this year. I also tried it with some of my friends accounts and with them its the same. There are seemingly no matches from 2020 or before. So I think that I basically cant get any match data from last year or the years before.
Is that true?

I am using the `/lol/match/v5/matches/by-puuid/{puuid}/ids` endpoint to get the matches.

Comment: Have you tried asking the maintainers of that API about this?

Comment: [Matches are kept for 2 years, timelines for 1 year.](https://riot-api-libraries.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specifics.html), so you should ask the maintainers...